# Ecto - The right way of migrating a field to a different type using custom logic?

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework, database-migration, ecto

I have a column `:from`, which was originally of type `{:array, :string}`. Now I want to migrate this column to be of type `:string`, taking the first entry of the array as the new value.

In Rails, you can do it with some custom logic in the migration. I'm trying to do the same with Ecto, but have run into problems due to schema validation and changeset errors.

```
defmodule Assistant.Repo.Migrations.ChangeFromFieldOnMails do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def up do
    dict_of_froms =
      Assistant.Mail
      |> Assistant.Repo.all()
      |> Enum.reduce(%{}, fn mail, acc ->
        Map.put(acc, mail.id, List.first(mail.from))
      end)

    alter table(:mails) do
      remove :from
      add :from, :string
    end

    Assistant.Mail
    |> Assistant.Repo.all()
    |> Enum.each(fn mail ->
      changeset = Ecto.Changeset.change(mail, from: Map.get(dict_of_froms, mail.id))
      Assistant.Repo.update!(changeset)
    end)
  end

  def down do
    dict_of_froms =
      Assistant.Mail
      |> Assistant.Repo.all()
      |> Enum.reduce(%{}, fn mail, acc ->
        Map.put(acc, mail.id, [mail.from])
      end)

    alter table(:mails) do
      remove :from
      add :from, {:array, :string}
    end

    Assistant.Mail
    |> Assistant.Repo.all()
    |> Enum.each(fn mail ->
      changeset = Ecto.Changeset.change(mail, from: Map.get(dict_of_froms, mail.id))
      Assistant.Repo.update!(changeset)
    end)
  end
end
```

The problem is that, I'll also have to change `field :from, {:array, :string}` to `field :from, :string` in my `Mail` schema, and this causes problems with the validation.

In the `up` step, `Assistant.Repo.all()` would fail because Ecto cannot load the `from` field from the old DB due to a type mismatch.

In the `down` step, `Assistant.Repo.update!(changeset)` would fail because `Ecto.Changeset` reported a type mismatch error on `:from`.

In Rails, there isn't really a strict check against the schema so you can get away with the code.

What is the right way of performing such migrations with Ecto? Is there no other way than writing custom SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the solution by apelsinka223 I was able to make it compile and work.

Some points worth noting:

- I had to call [`flush()`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto_sql/Ecto.Migration.html#module-flushing) midway through the `up` and `down` functions, otherwise the removal and addition of columns wouldn't happen in time.
- If a query is not based on a schema, one would need to explicitly use the `select` statement in the query for Ecto to run it.
- `update_all()` needs at least two arguments. One can pass in `[]` as the second argument.

```
defmodule Assistant.Repo.Migrations.ChangeFromFieldOnMails do
  use Ecto.Migration
  import Ecto.Query, only: [from: 2]
  alias Assistant.Repo

  def up do
    query = from(m in "mails", select: {m.id, m.from})

    dict_of_froms =
      query
      |> Repo.all()
      |> Enum.reduce(%{}, fn {id, from}, acc ->
        Map.put(acc, id, List.first(from))
      end)

    alter table(:mails) do
      remove :from
      add :from, :string
    end

    flush()

    dict_of_froms
    |> Enum.each(fn {id, fr} ->
      query =
        from(m in "mails",
          where: m.id == ^id,
          update: [set: [from: ^fr]]
        )

      Repo.update_all(query, [])
    end)
  end

  def down do
    query = from(m in "mails", select: {m.id, m.from})

    dict_of_froms =
      query
      |> Repo.all()
      |> Enum.reduce(%{}, fn {id, from}, acc ->
        Map.put(acc, id, [from])
      end)

    alter table(:mails) do
      remove :from
      add :from, {:array, :string}
    end

    flush()

    dict_of_froms
    |> Enum.each(fn {id, fr} ->
      query =
        from(m in "mails",
          where: m.id == ^id,
          update: [set: [from: ^fr]]
        )

      Repo.update_all(query, [])
    end)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to avoid using Structs and Changeset in migrations. Use `Repo.insert_all`, `Repo.update_all` and schema namings instead.

```
defmodule Assistant.Repo.Migrations.ChangeFromFieldOnMails do
  use Ecto.Migration
  import Ecto.Query

  def up do
    dict_of_froms =
      "mails"                # table name as string
      |> Assistant.Repo.all()
      |> Enum.reduce(%{}, fn mail, acc ->
        Map.put(acc, mail.id, List.first(mail.from))
      end)

    alter table(:mails) do
      remove :from
      add :from, :string
    end

    dict_of_froms
    |> Enum.each(fn {id, from} ->   # changed this cycle little bit, so it would
         "mails"                    # update record only if we have `from` for it
         |> where(id: ^id)
         |> update(set: [from: ^from])
         |> Repo.update_all()
    end) 
  end

  def down do
    dict_of_froms =
      "mails"
      |> Assistant.Repo.all()
      |> Enum.reduce(%{}, fn mail, acc ->
        Map.put(acc, mail.id, [mail.from])
      end)

    alter table(:mails) do
      remove :from
      add :from, {:array, :string}
    end

    dict_of_froms
    |> Enum.each(fn {id, from} ->   # changed this cycle little bit, so it would
         "mails"                    # update record only if we have `from` for it
         |> where(id: ^id)
         |> update(set: [from: ^from])
         |> Repo.update_all()
    end) 
  end
end
```

Not sure that all code is clean and compilable, but a hope my idea is clear

Comment: Thanks. I think what I need is exactly a way to circumvent struct and changeset validations. I'll modify and test out the solution tomorrow.

Comment: Where are `where()` and `update()` defined?  You have a `use Ecto.Migration` statement, but I looked there. Nada. Okay, I seem them in `Ecto.Query`.

Comment: @7stud you are right, I added `import Ecto.Query` to example

Comment: I was able to make the code compile and work after some modifications. I posted the final code below.